# Chrome extension - message port closed before a response was received

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I get this error in my simple chrome extension. I'm trying to pass some messages from background.js to my content script. The first message will be sent without problems, but the second one give me this error `_generated_background_page.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

I need to pass a response from the content script after the first message is recived, this because I need to remove event listener from `webRequest.onCompleted` otherwise I will get a loop problem with message passing. I'm not sure if I'm doing the things well also with `removeListener` function.

Here is my code, any help will be appreciated

contentScript.js

```
const m3u8 = new M3U8(); 
console.log(m3u8);
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( message => {    
    console.log(message);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({status: 'ok'})
    const download = m3u8.start(message.url);
    download.on("progress", progress => {
        console.log(progress);
    }).on("finished", finished => {
        console.log(finished);
    }).on("error", error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

background.js

```
const sendURL = (request) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(request.tabId, {url: request.url}, response => {
        if( response.status === 'ok' ){
            chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.removeListener( sendURL )
        }
        return true;
    })
}

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( request => {
    console.log(request);
    sendURL(request)
},{
    urls: ["https://*.myurl.net/*/*prog_index.m3u8*"],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
},["responseHeaders"]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were sending a new message, not a response. And it failed because there was no corresponding onMessage in the background script.

Let's use the [simple messaging example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) correctly.

1. Add `sendResponse` parameter to onMessage:

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
   ```
2. Use `sendResponse` instead of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {  
     sendResponse({status: 'ok'});
     //.........
   });
   ```

Comment: ok, thank you, I will fix the code. For the listener, is the code ok instead? I'm not sure if the listener is removed

Comment: It's not removed. You need to use addListener(sendURL) instead of addListener(request => {
    console.log(request);
    sendURL(request)
})

Comment: I've fixed the code, I'm able to `console.log()` the response that is send from the content script. The problem is now that the message is sent in a loop and the `removeListener` will not fire.

Comment: ok, I will try and let you know. the `request` will be passed implicitly to the function right?

Comment: Weird that you need to call `sendResponse` to avoid the error, since the documentation states it's optional. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage

Comment: @Protectorone, see [this answer](/a/59915897/) for more info.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there an overview of possible communication channels between extension parts `background.js - content.js, content.js - popup.js, popup.js - background.js, content.js - background.js, ... `
Is it possible to communicate from any part to any part?

Comment: @Legends, there's [messaging article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) in the documentation. For the popup-SW route there's native navigator.serviceWorker messaging.